# C# - Java interoperation

Tags: c#, java, interop

Can you give me some pointers on making C# code and Java code interoperate? 
Let's define the interoperation as something simple: allow (from Java code) the instantiantion and method calling of a class defined in C#, and, possibly, the other way around as well.

Is this even possible *natively*? (i.e. without some proxy/skeleton interface mechanism)

And finally, what proxy mechanisms can be used? (i.e. are supported by both language realms)

Comment: creating a class that is defined in a different byte-code format is simple now? :/

Answer (score 6):

I've used [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to accomplish this successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a very promising article on CodeProject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Espresso.aspx).

Excerpt from the article introduction:

> The suggested solution will show how
>   the two frameworks can live together
>   in the same process and communicate
>   seamlessly with each other.
>
> This article describes a
>   high-performing interoperability
>   solution between the Java platform and
>   the .NET Framework. The suggested
>   solution does not replace the Java
>   Virtual Machine or the .NET Framework
>   runtime, instead, your JVM or .NET are
>   each hosted within the opposing
>   runtime environment, ensuring that
>   vendor-specific VM optimizations are
>   preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what needs to be done on the .NET side (I'm not a .NET guy), but Java provides the JNI framework for interoperating with native libraries.

Start with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), then follow the links...

Answer (score 1):

I am author of [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net/), open source interprocess bridge between JVM and CLR. It's build on top of JNI and PInvoke. No C/C++ code needed. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few third-party products that can do .NET-Java interop natively. [J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/) is the one I'm most familiar with (I don't work for them nor do I have any economic interest in them).

If you're ok with proxies and the like, you have a few options like SOAP/Web Services or CORBA.

Answer (score 0):

A quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+.net) finds [this page on "Java + .NET Integration Scenarios"](http://www.infoq.com/j+n/)