# Using java library from .NET

Tags: java, .net, interop

What is the best way to use java library from .NET?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171717/using-java-classes-with-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129989/how-to-call-java-code-from-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191622/c-java-interoperation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/)

I don't know if it is *the best way*, but it's the only one I know...

Answer (score 0):

With the 2003 version of their tools, Microsoft had something called the [Java Language Conversion Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=46bea47e-d47f-4349-9b4f-904b0a973174&displaylang=en) which would convert Java to C#.  I've used it -- it kind of sort of mostly works.