# Interface Callback in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to write a interface callback from a java library inside Xamarin using c#, Below is the code snippet,

```
Connector.getInstance().login(email, new ILoginCallback() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(long heloUserId) {
/* call the required Activity for successful login */
}
@Override
public void onPinverification() {
/*call the Pin verification activity to validate pin */
}
@Override
public void onFailure(String description) {
/*show the toast msg for failure*/
}
});
```

I am unable to do interface callback in c# which blocked me to get the success or failure result.

Any Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your interface on a class that inherits from `Java.Lang.Object`:

```
public class MyLoginCallback : Java.Lang.Object, ILoginCallback
{
   // implement the interface
}
```

And then use that C# class that also now has a Android Callable Wrapper (ACW) as your callback instance.

Something like:

```
Connector.Instance.Login(email, new MyLoginCallback();
```

Re: [Android Callable Wrappers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately but the code is still not working. Can you please elaborate more.

Comment: I did something like this,

    public partial class HeloLogin : ContentPage
    {
       
        private void OnRegister(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connector.Instance.Login(Email.Text, new XYZ());

        }

    }

    public class XYZ : Java.Lang.Object, ILoginCallback
    {
    
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void OnFailure(string p0)
        {

        }

        public void OnPinverification()
        {

        }

        public void OnSuccess(long p0)
        {
            
        }
    }

Comment: @user6352350 That is not telling me what is not "working"

Comment: I placed breakpoints on each method. but nothing gets hit after callback line executed.

Comment: @user6352350 You would need to debug whatever `Connector.Instance.Login` does...  I would have no idea what it does or what Java library is bound.

Comment: Can you please skype on anuragc64 ?

Comment: @SushiHangover, I implemented the interface as you said. It throws error when the callback in Android binding trying to execute my callback as **System.NotSupportedException  Message=Unable to activate instance of type myapppackage.Droid.MyCallback from native handle 0xAxyz (key_handle 0xyue736)**

Comment: @ThamaraiT post a new question with your code

Comment: @SushiHangover, [question is already here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420680/how-to-implement-ipay88-payment-gateway-sdk). Kindly refer this.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your interface as like below

```
public class MyLoginCallback : Java.Lang.Object, ILoginCallback, ISerializable
{    
   public MyLoginCallback()
   { }

   public MyLoginCallback(IntPtr intPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership handleOwnership)
   { }

   // implement the interface methods here
}
```