# ipay88 (Payment Gateway) with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway

I am integrating ipay88 payment gateway with Laravel framework. I have successfully integrated the payment gateway and the user is able to reach the payment page, the error is in the redirect page after payment done/cancel, the error is "

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> GET, HEAD."
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:
> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> GET, HEAD.

In my web.php I have this route:

```
Route::get('/get/renter/payment/status', 'OB@getpaymentstatus');
```

and I have added this rout to be excepted from CSRF token in VerifyCsrfToken

Could you please advise how to resolve this issue. Thank you

Comment: check which page you are redirecitng back .is it same get/renter/payment/status.

Comment: Yes John it is the same

Comment: try changing Route::any or just try accessing /get/renter/payment/status url in browser .or else post full web.php in question.Also addd VerifyCsrfToken middleware code too

Comment: I have tried the following and it worked: Route::any('get/renter/payment/status', 'OB@getpaymentstatus');
Thank you so much John, I have tried get and post but poth did not work, as the payment gateway is sending post response so post should work right?

Comment: @OsamaShaki can you help me integrate ipay88

Comment: @Sohil what is the problem you are facing? are you able to follow their api doc or not?

Comment: can you please answer this question for me. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67996664/how-to-integrate-ipay88-payment-gateway-with-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67996664/how-to-integrate-ipay88-payment-gateway-with-laravel) Thanks.

Comment: @OsamaShaki can you share me a code ipay88 integration step by step

Comment: @MalikZubairMukhtar you can find all the details in their documentation, please have a look and let me know your issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the following and it worked: Route::any('get/renter/payment/status', 'OB@getpaymentstatus');
Thank you all.

Comment: Could you kindly help me how to resolve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421511/4574300)?

Comment: which issue? it is better to add a new question and explain further.

Comment: I am facing callback issue as in that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421511/4574300) and also added my issue in comments too.

Answer (score 1):

Look Like Payment gateway sending Post request so you can do the following

```
Route::post('/get/renter/payment/status', 'OB@getpaymentstatus');
```

or you can allow all request if you needed

```
Route::any('/get/renter/payment/status', 'OB@getpaymentstatus');
```

To verify which method is payment gateway is sending .You can do the following inside `getpaymentstatus` method.While trying below code change to route to any so you can verify easily

```
dd($request->method());
```

Comment: Yes it is sending post, I have tried the first one and it did not work so the second one worked for me.. Thank you